# Issue with if-statement with getters

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, getter-setter

My task is to develop an application that tests my Robot class.  The test application will ask the user for the robots name.  It will then instantiate a Robot object using the name.  The application will then use  loop to ask the user to enter direction (x or y) to move and the distance.  The loop will terminate when the user enters a direction of q (for quit).  Once the loop is done, the program will display the robots final position and the total distance traveled.

My main issue is trying to work with my Robot class and testing it in my Prog3 class when it comes to my if statement.  Here is my Robot class:

```
public class Robot {
private String name;
private int xPosition;
private int yPosition;
private int totalDistance;

public Robot(String name, int xPosition, int yPosition, int totalDistance){
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.xPosition = 0;
    this.yPosition = 0;
    this.totalDistance = totalDistance;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getxPosition() {
    return xPosition;
}

public int getyPosition() {
    return yPosition;
}

public int getTotalDistance() {
    return totalDistance;
}

public void moveX(int distance){
    xPosition += distance;
    totalDistance += Math.abs(distance);
}

public void moveY(int distance){
    yPosition += distance;
    totalDistance += Math.abs(distance);
}



}
```

Now here is my Prog3 class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Prog3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    //asks the user for robots name
    System.out.print("Enter robots name; ");
    Robot.name = in.nextLine();

    //asks the user to move the robot
    System.out.print("Direction of move (x/y/q): ");
    String move = in.nextLine();

    if( move.equals("x") ){
        System.out.print("Distance: ");

    }
    else if( move.equals("y") ){
        System.out.print("Distance: ");

    }
    else{


    }

}
}
```

As you can see, my Prog3 class is not complete due to the fact that i am completely stuck.  Thank you so much for your time as it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `else if (move.equals("q") { System.exit(0); }`? I don't see a question in your post, but I feel like you're asking how to handle the quit condition.

Comment: Im not even sure if i should use an if statement when it comes to finding out if the user wants to move the robot x or y.  Also, i dont understand how i am supposed to use my getters within my test (they are required for grade).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your constructor does not make sense, why would you need to input x and y values if they are always set to 0?

I wrote you a new blank constructor, and added some setters methods

```
public class Robot {
private String name;
private int xPosition;
private int yPosition;
private int totalDistance;

public Robot(){
    name = null;
    xPosition = 0;
    yPosition = 0;
    totalDistance = 0;
}

public Robot(String name, int xPosition, int yPosition, int totalDistance){
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.xPosition = 0;
    this.yPosition = 0;
    this.totalDistance = totalDistance;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName( String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public int getxPosition() {
    return xPosition;
}

public void setxPosition(int x) {
    xPosition = x;
}

public int getyPosition() {
    return yPosition;
}

public void setyPosition(int y){
    yPosition = y;
}

public int getTotalDistance() {
    return totalDistance;
}


public void moveX(int distance){
    xPosition += distance;
    totalDistance += Math.abs(distance);
}

public void moveY(int distance){
    yPosition += distance;
    totalDistance += Math.abs(distance);
}
```

then you need to do something with all of that in your main class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Prog3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Robot robo = new Robot();

    //asks the user for robots name
    System.out.print("Enter robots name: ");
    String myName = in.next();
    robo.setName(myName);


    while( true ){
    //asks the user to move the robot
    System.out.print("Direction of move (x/y/q): ");
    String direction = in.next();
    if(direction.equals("q"))
        break;

    System.out.println("Distance of move: ");
    int distance = in.nextInt();


    if (direction.equals("x")) {
        robo.moveX(distance);
        System.out.println("moved" + distance +"units along the x axis");
    }
    else if (direction.equals("y")) {
        robo.moveY(distance);
        System.out.println("moved " + distance +" units along the y axis");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
    }

    System.out.println("moved " + robo.getTotalDistance() + " total distance");

}
}
```

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thank you so much, this honestly was exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

"The loop will terminate when the user enters a direction of q (for quit).". Your program is not looping:

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Robot robot = new Robot();

//asks the user for robots name
System.out.print("Enter robots name; ");
Robot.name = in.nextLine();

//asks the user to move the robot
System.out.print("Direction of move (x/y/q): ");
String move = in.nextLine();

if( move.equals("x") ){
    System.out.print("Distance: ");

}
else if( move.equals("y") ){
    System.out.print("Distance: ");

}
else{


}
```

This code segment will only run once...If you want it to loop you need an actual

```
 While(<Conditional>) { 
// your code here
// a break point to exit the loop ( in your case "q" as the input string )
} // end while...
```

Also I was a bit confused as the wording of your question is a bit ambiguous. What exactly is the nature of your issue?

Comment: Yeah, i realized my post is pretty grand when it comes to a specific question.  Thank you for your time, but how could i write the while(<Conditional>). As im not sure what to put i resorted to an if statement, which obviously is not working either

Comment: If your asking how to write the loop use the while loop I gave above ( maybe like while( true ) and use Savardi's example as the break point conditional.....However, if this is for a class you really should understand how control structures work. If you are using java: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm

Comment: Also back to the original question to access a property of a class you would do something like: this.totalDistance << reference to property

Comment: Thank you, i believe i can figure it out from here.  I appreciate your time.